# select group with multiselect

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

I am new to multiselect. I am using bootstrap multiselect for selecting student list, here groups(which are group of students) and list of students that i am displaying as snapshot. I am unable to add snapshot as i don't have a reputation. please view this link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3-rBrGTl5UfTHZINHRtMzU5Wnc/view?usp=sharing. Now when i select group it should automatically select students which are belong to group. I find using optgroup but it is not usefull as it will have group label then student list(here student may belong to multiple group so i display group and student list differently).

Please help.

Comment: Add your html and your js, at least the important parts

Comment: this is link i am working on. http://chenjidesigns.com/practut/progress-report.html hope this helps or i can write html and js here if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a jquery plugin :

http://uoziod.github.io/deep-checkbox/

Its very easy to use :

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" data-id="item" data-name="Item" /> Item
            <ul>
                <li><input type="checkbox" data-id="subitem1" data-name="Subitem 1" /> Subitem 1</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" data-id="subitem2" data-name="Subitem 2" /> Subitem 2</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" data-name="Subitem 3" /> Subitem 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    $('.wrapper').deepcheckbox();
</script>
```

Comment: Here student will be inside group and same student will appear multiple times when student have multiple group. so i need sequential list of unique students and group and purpose is if group/student are checked relevant students/group should be checked and this is dropdown list. here is the link what i've been used. http://chenjidesigns.com/practut/progress-report.html